# is it possible to make function that will accept multiple data types for given argument?

Tags: c++, function, variables, types

Writing a function I must declare input and output data types like this:

```
int my_function (int argument) {}
```

Is it possible to make such a declaration that my function would accept variable of type int, bool or char, and can output these data types ?

```
//non working example
[int bool char] my_function ([int bool char] argument) {}
```

Comment: you need to look into templates

Comment: it's called [templates](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~kathy/vcstl/templates.htm)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Your link gives a 403 error

Comment: @pkqxdd: yeah, sometimes links die. Anyhow, you can just google for "c++ templates" and pick one of the first few links. Today it's [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your choices are

**ALTERNATIVE 1**

You can use templates

```
template <typename T> 
T myfunction( T t )
{
    return t + t;
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE 2**

Plain function overloading

```
bool myfunction(bool b )
{
}

int myfunction(int i )
{
}
```

You provide a different function for each  type of each argument you expect. You can mix it Alternative 1. The compiler will the right one for you.

**ALTERNATIVE 3**

You can use union

```
union myunion
{ 
    int i;
    char c;
    bool b;
};

myunion my_function( myunion u ) 
{
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE 4**

You can use polymorphism. Might be an overkill for int , char , bool but useful for more complex  class types.

```
class BaseType
{
public:
    virtual BaseType*  myfunction() = 0;
    virtual ~BaseType() {}
};

class IntType : public BaseType
{
    int X;
    BaseType*  myfunction();
};

class BoolType  : public BaseType
{
    bool b;
    BaseType*  myfunction();
};

class CharType : public BaseType
{
    char c;
    BaseType*  myfunction();
};

BaseType*  myfunction(BaseType* b)
{
    //will do the right thing based on the type of b
    return b->myfunction();
}
```

Comment: Why not add boost::any, void*, and boost::variant? Might as well go the full way.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg Please feel free to edit the answer... I usually like to stick to standard C++

Comment: Op asks to return the same type as the argument, not `int` every time

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T f(T arg)
{
    return arg;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f(33) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f('a') << std::endl;
    std::cout << f(true) << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
33
a
1
```

Or you can do:

```
int i = f(33);
char c = f('a');
bool b = f(true);
```

Comment: @Rhexis, in this case it implicitly infers the value of the 'typename T' based on what type the argument of the function 'f()' is

Answer (score 4):

Use a [template](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/):

```
template <typename T>
T my_function(T arg) {
  // Do stuff
}

int a = my_function<int>(4);
```

Or just overload:

```
int my_function(int a) { ... }
char my_function(char a) { ... }
bool my_function(bool a) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

read this tutorial, it gives some nice examples http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.