# Function with generic input parameters

Tags: c++, generics

I am relatively new to c++. I wrote function `WriteToFile`, which writes in text file (path is specified by string `a`) 2D array (stored in 0-row major order, x rows, y columns):

```
void WriteToFile(std::string a, const float *img, const int x, const int y) {
    FILE *pFile;
    const char * c = a.c_str();
    pFile = fopen(c, "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            fprintf(pFile, "%5.5f\t", img[i*y + j]);
        fprintf(pFile, "\n");
    }
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Now I want this function to deal also with  `int` and `double`  arrays. For `int` it will just print numbers as it is, and for double `%5.10lf` must be used in `fprintf`. I know, that it is absolutely possible. I found couple similar things, but didn't get how do deal with input arguments. Of course, I can write 3 different functions, but I want to learn how can I write generic function.

Thanks

Comment: The format specifier depends on type of array, so probably you need three different calls/logic to figure at some point in this code, or may be pass addition args to figure out the type

Comment: You could use the `fstream` class and either add an overloaded `operator<<` in your matrix class or use a free standing function to write the 2d array to the `fstream`.  The `fstream` is already set up to handle other object types like `double`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to make function that will accept multiple data types for given argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627625/is-it-possible-to-make-function-that-will-accept-multiple-data-types-for-given-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function template and some helper functions to get the format string.

Here's a working program.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template <typename T> char const* getFormatString();

template <> char const* getFormatString<int>()
{
   return "%d\t";
}

template <> char const* getFormatString<float>()
{
   return "%5.5f\t";
}

template <> char const* getFormatString<double>()
{
   return "%15.10lf\t";
}

template <typename T>
void WriteToFile(std::string a, const T *img, const int x, const int y) {
    FILE *pFile;
    const char * c = a.c_str();
    pFile = fopen(c, "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            fprintf(pFile, getFormatString<T>(), img[i*y + j]);
        fprintf(pFile, "\n");
    }
    fclose(pFile);
}

int main()
{
   int img1[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
   float img2[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
   double img3[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
   WriteToFile("int.img", img1, 2, 2);
   WriteToFile("float.img", img2, 2, 2);
   WriteToFile("double.img", img3, 2, 2);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like this !

Answer (score 3):

> *"Now I want this function to deal also with `int` and `double` arrays. "*

You can use a templated function to handle different types of arrays, and use the c++ standard I/O library

```
template <typename T>
void WriteToFile(std::string a, const T *img, const int x, const int y) {
    std::ofstream file(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            file << std::fixed << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(5) 
                 << img[i*y + j] << "\t" << std::endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

You may consider to have specialized implementations for different formatting needs.

Comment: If specialization comes into picture, then that's not what OP asked

Comment: @P0W `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` wouldn't affect `int` output anyway.

Comment: Agreed but what if decimal precision differs for `float` and `double`, you'll have to specialize

Comment: @P0W Yes, I've spotted this requirement now in the OP. Upvoted R.Sahu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have options such as overloading and template functions. I just want to introduce an ability which comes with C++11. Using [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

It has its pros and cons. For example, assume the input type is limited to `int` and `float`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void WriteToFile(std::string a, const T *img, const int x, const int y)
{
   const char *format = std::is_same<T, int>::value? "%i\t" : "%5.5f\t";

   ...

      fprintf(pFile, format, img[i*y + j]);

   ...
}
```

Note that, this approach is against generalization and your code is not as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a different format string for each type, you can use a templated function and pass in the format string as a parameter:

```
template<typename T> void WriteToFile(std::string a, const T *img, 
                      const int x, const int y, std::string formatStr) {
...
       fprintf(pFile, formatStr.c_str(), img[i*y + j]); 
...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

An idea would be

```
template <typename T>
void WriteToFile(std::string a, const T *img, const int x, const int y) {
}
```

and then a

```
inline
void write(FILE *file, double) { //write double }

inline
void write(FILE *file, int) { // write }
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid separate calls