# How does std::sort() get both iterators and pointers?

Tags: c++, templates

As in the title, how does `std::sort()` gets iterators and pointers? Can someone tell how it is implemented?

`std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())`

`std::sort(arr, arr + arr_size)`

Comment: [c++ - is it possible to make function that will accept multiple data types for given argument? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627625/is-it-possible-to-make-function-that-will-accept-multiple-data-types-for-given-a)

Comment: Formally pointers *are* iterators.

Comment: pointers _are_ random-access iterators, as they conform to all their requirements; hence, a template algorithm written to work with the requirements for random-access iterators will work with pointer just fine.

Comment: @user463035818 [There is no overload for `std::sort` that takes pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: @user202729 meh sorry I was a bit confused and the comments lead nowhere, ill delete them

Comment: Iterator is a concept. An algorithm that accepts a certain type of iterator is simply a template that expect it's template argument(s) to respect a certain set of requirements. An iterator can be *any* object that respects those requirements. Pointer just so happen (by design) to satisfy all of the requirements for being a random access iterator.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's unclear what you mean. All overloads of `std::sort` take pointers.

Comment: @eerorika I was talking to a now deleted comment.  It said the function was overloaded to take pointers.  My link shows this is not the case, it is just a template and it will accept pointers since they are random access iterators.  If the function was actually overloaded for pointers it would have `T*` parameters.