# Can a C++ function receive two types in one argument alternatively?

Tags: c++, function, integer, arguments

I wish to send an integer to a function, that integer might be 8/16 bits depending on conditions. Can I declare one function to receive either int8/in16 as argument, depending on what the caller sends? Or, do I have to declare two functions one for each type (what I am doing at present)?

void func(uint8_t/uint16_t value)

or

void func(uint8_t value)
void func(uint16_t value)

Comment: You are looking for a [template function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-cpp/)

Comment: You forgot about `template <typename T> void func(T value)`

Comment: If the function is a method within a class you can also use [overloading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm).

Comment: @havakok Why did you link a python answer to a C++ question?  And that GFG website is one that has a very low reputation as far as learning C++ goes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did not. It was generated automatically when I clicked by mistake when voting to close. Deleted it.

Comment: I can suggest [this cpp answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627625/is-it-possible-to-make-function-that-will-accept-multiple-data-types-for-given-a) though.

Comment: The link was for python I think. Thanks for the overloading hint, it's exactly inside a class.

Comment: Which solution is "best" depends rather a lot on what the function does.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using function template and SFINAE as shown below:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t>> func(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << "uint8 version called" <<std::endl;
}
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, uint16_t>> func(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << "uint16 version called" <<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
     uint8_t x = 4;
     func(x);         //calls uint8 version

     uint16_t y = 4;
     func(y);         //calls uint16_t version
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, this doesn't answer the question, which asks for _one_ function, not two.

Comment: @cptFracassa How can this possibly be done with a single function. C++ is a statically typed language.

Comment: Jason Liam: By having one template function, see my answer.

Comment: @cptFracassa A "function template" is not actually a function! OP can use/choose whichever version(your's or mine) that they might find useful.

Comment: Jason: I am fully aware that the _compiler_ creates two functions for my code, but I am only declaring one. You are writing two while the original post specifically asked if it was possible to declare only one function - not how to write two functions which prevents any implicit casting, which your solution is an answer to.
To me it looks like you misread the question.

Comment: @cptFracassa I agree but note that it is very **trivial** to combine both the function templates into one by using a `||` (as you did in your example). So if OP really only needs to declare it one time then they can do it(as it is trivial and a good exercise for OP). This is also good because, then my answer doesn't completely spoon feed by leaving that trivial thing out.

Comment: Jason: I gave a +1 to your last comment, as I agree to that.

Answer (score 1):

@Jason Liam is onto it, but if you want to different functions, standard overloading is the answer. If you want to use a single function for those two types, combine Jason's functions:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T> void func(const T& t) requires 
    std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t> || std::is_same_v<T, uint16_t>
{
    std::cout << "called with type " << typeid(T).name() <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
     uint8_t x = 4;
     func(x);         //calls uint8_t version

     uint16_t y = 4;
     func(y);         //calls uint16_t version

     int z = 6;
//     func(z);  compiler error, z is not right type
}
```

[Test in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bvW19scxY)

Answer (score 0):

With C++20, we can use `requires` clause instead of SFINAE to do the same:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> void func(const T& t) requires std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t>
{
    std::cout << "uint8 version called" <<std::endl;
}
template <typename T> void func(const T& t) requires std::is_same_v<T, uint16_t>
{
    std::cout << "uint16 version called" <<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
     uint8_t x = 4;
     func(x);         //calls uint8 version

     uint16_t y = 4;
     func(y);         //calls uint16_t version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void func(uint8_t/uint16_t value)
```

The only way to do this exactly (without a function template instantiated as two functions) is with [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (or some other discriminated union).

```
void func(std::variant<uint8_t, uint16_t> value)
{
}
```

is precisely what you requested.

When you start *implementing* the body, you'll find it's often simpler to delegate to a templated visitor, and then you're back to the existing answers (but with a relatively expensive runtime decision about the type instead of a static one).

Demonstration [in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q4h1TMjzc)

```
void func(std::variant<uint8_t, uint16_t> value)
{
    std::cout << "called with type index " << value.index() << '\n';

    // templated visitor
    std::visit(
        [](auto && val)
        {
            std::cout << "called with type " << typeid(val).name()
             << ", value " << val << '\n';
        },
        value
        );
        
    // alternatively, test each type by hand
    if (std::holds_alternative<uint8_t>(value))
    {
        std::cout << "got uint8_t alternative " << std::get<uint8_t>(value)
        << '\n';
    }
    else if (std::holds_alternative<uint16_t>(value))
    {
        std::cout << "got uint16_t alternative " << std::get<uint16_t>(value)
        << '\n';
    }
}
```